# Jenkins how to schedule two builds if one of the builds executes every minute?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

**Project A** executes continuously at around every minute

How can I also execute **Project B** every 2 hours?

At the time of **Project B's** execution **Project A** must be disabled / not executed.

Comment: By Build A and B you mean different projects, jobs or build commands?

Comment: @Rafael Cost thanks for the comment, i mean different projects

Comment: Check my answer, i think i didn't understood the question 100% so give it some feedback =)

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on **how you want things to run**. If your Jenkins instance only have **1 slave** with 1 job concurrency configured, you don't have to worry about build concurrency if there is two projects trying to build. One of them is gonna be picked and built, and then the another.

If i'm not wrong, Jenkins has 3 builders per slave for default, so probably the 2 projects would run at the same time. But you can always go on Configurations and tweak that.

Comment: thanks, both projects currently execute automation tests copying code from a remote repo, when execute both projects concurrently it takes allot of time, do you think its best to use a master and a series of slaves?

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline { 
options { lock resource: 'build-lock' } 
stages {...} 
}
```

use this in both of your pipelines. At any given point in time, either A or B will execute.

For more info [Lockable resources](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Lockable+Resources+Plugin)